# Retrieving members from a DL in LDAP using C#

Tags: c#, list, ldap, directorysearcher

Thanks marc_s for getting back.

I tried the following code:

```
public void GetInfo()
{
    try
    {
        //Object obj;
        DirectorySearcher search;
        DirectoryEntry entry;
        SearchResult result;
        String mailid = "";
        bool flag = false;

        entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPpath);//, Domainwithuser, password);

        search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "CN=DistributionList1";

        int i = search.Filter.Length;

        string str = "", str1 = "";

        foreach (SearchResult AdObj in search.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (String objName in AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["member"])
            {
                str += Convert.ToString(objName) + "&lt;Br>";
                int selIndex = objName.IndexOf("CN=") + 3;
                int selEnd = objName.IndexOf(",OU") - 3;
                str1 += objName.Substring(selIndex, selEnd).Replace("\\", "") + "&lt;BR>";

                DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                dsSearch.Filter = "CN=" + objName.Substring(selIndex, selEnd).Replace("\\", "");

                foreach (SearchResult rs in dsSearch.FindAll())
                {
                    str1 += "&lt;p align='right'><font face='calibri' color='#2266aa' size=2>" + Convert.ToString(rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value) + "|" + Convert.ToString(rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayName"].Value) + "|" + Convert.ToString(rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value) + "|" + Convert.ToString(rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value) + "|" + Convert.ToString(rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberOf"].Value) + "&lt;/font></p>";
                }
            }
        }

        Response.Write("&lt;BR>" + str + "&lt;Br>" + str1 + "&lt;BR>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("--unable to fetch--<BR>" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here, `search.findAll` throws a `DirectoryCOMException` saying

> invalid dn in syntax

I have a requirement to fetch all the email addresses that belong to a distribution list.

I did try implementing the approach detailed out in the below link but unfortunately it didn't work:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1224607.aspx?Displaying+Members+in+a+Distribution+List

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried - where are you stuck? We'll **help** - but we won't just write the whole code for you ...

Comment: Hi marc_s, I have updated my original post.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. This makes your life a *whole lot* easier than the old, rather clunky `DirectorySearcher` ...

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - limit to the OU you're interested in
// use this constructor if you want just the default domain, and search in the whole domain
//     using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null))
// or use this line here to define a *container* to search inside of 
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "OU=YourOU,DC=YourCompany,DC=Com"))
{
    // find the group in question - this can be either a DL, or a security group - both should be found just fine
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
           // do whatever you need to do to those members
       }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Read more about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Also: I strongly recommend to **clearly and strictly** keeping the *fetching* of the data and the *displaying* separate - don't intermix fetching with HTML representation - that's just a huge "ball of mud" style code - ***NOT*** recommended!

Have **one method** that retrieves the data you need, into e.g. a `List<UserPrincipal>` (or you can also define your own class to hold the data you need), and then have a **second**, separate method that get this information from the first method and iterates over it to display it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this out and let you know if it worked. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I get S.DS.AM.PrincipalOperationException with InnerException="A referral was eturned from the server" on executing GroupPricipal.FindByIdentity method.

Comment: using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null,"OU=End Users,OU=Accounts,DC=nos,DC=<my dc>,DC=<My comp name>,DC=com"))
        {                    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,"<DL display name>");
                                         foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
                              }
           
        }